# Variable declaration dramatically increasing query time

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables

I have an existing query that I use to update a table:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
INTO ...
WHERE ... AND date >= '2021-07-01' AND date < '2021-07-05'
```

There is quite a few `JOIN` and `WHERE` clauses but the query returns 1.5m rows and executes in ~6 seconds.

I'm looking to automate this using the below code. I originally wrote the `DECLARE` statements  to be based on the latest existing date and the current date but simplified it to try and identify the cause and to make it clearer in this post.

```
DECLARE @date1 AS DATE = '2021-07-01'
DECLARE @date2 AS DATE = '2021-07-05'
SELECT ...
FROM ...
INTO ...
WHERE ... AND date >= @date1 AND date < @date2
```

This query is identical to the first except declaring dates up front but now this code takes dramatically longer to execute - I cancelled after ~20 mins.

Any ideas on causes and/or solutions?

Comment: *"I have an existing query that I use to update a table:"* That statement isn't  an `UPDATE`; it `CREATE`s a table, with the definition based on the columns returned from the `SELECT`, and then `INSERT`s the data from the `SELECT` into it. It doesn't perform any like of `UPDATE`.

Comment: I believe the problem is in query plan. Would you try adding an "option (recompile)" option.

Comment: What is the data type of your column `date`?

Comment: @Larnu It's the first step in a longer code that does update a table at the end but probably directly for the question I shouldn't have used the word update. Column data type is ```(date, not null)```

Comment: @CetinBasoz I've never used that option before but I will certainly look into it.

Comment: It's generally better for "catch all" or "kitchen sink" queries, @DL1 . Though you could be falling afoul of parameter sniffing, and hence the recommendation.

Comment: Have you compared the execution plans? Using the variables will likely be causing SQL Server to use poor estimates and hence won't have chosen to seek to the range of rows required.

Comment: Please include the full query, the tables and index definitions, and share the slow and fast query plans via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan. I'm guessing because these are variable, they prevent parameter sniffing, so it's the same as `OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)`. There are methods to solve that but we need to see more detail. SQL performance doesn't usually work on "generalized" lines, it's very case-specific

Comment: The reason for this situation is that the query optimizer has no idea which value is held in the SQL variable so it can not use the histogram efficiently. As mentioned by the @CetinBasoz you can use option recompile or a dynamic query. https://www.sqlshack.com/impact-of-sql-variables-on-performance/